# LLVM how to get callsite file name and line number

Tags: c++, llvm

I am very very new to LLVM, and it's my first time to write C++

I need to find several function info related to LLVM CallSite, however, I have checked the source code here: [LLVM CallSite Source Code](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/CallSite_8h_source.html)

Still don't know where to get **call site file name** (eg. CallSite is in example.c file), **call site line number** (eg. at line 18 in the whole program)

Do you know how can I get call site file name and line number?

Answer (score 4):

You can get this information by retrieving debug information from the called function. The algorithm is the following:

1. You need to get underlying called value, which is a function.
2. Then you need to get debug information attached to that function.
3. The debug information should contain everything you need.

Here is a code that should do the job (I didn't run it though):

```
CallSite cs = ...;
if (!cs.isCall() && !cs.isInvoke()) {
  break;
}

Function *calledFunction = dyn_cast<Function>(cs.getCalledValue());
if (!calledFunction) {
  break;
}

MDNode *metadata = calledFunction->getMetadata(0);
if (!metadata) {
  break;
}

DILocation *debugLocation = dyn_cast<DILocation>(metadata);
if (debugLocation) {
  debugLocation->getFilename();
  debugLocation->getLine();
}
```

Please note the breaks. They are here to show that every step may not succeed, so you should be ready to handle all such cases.

Comment: He wants the location of the call, not the callee.

Comment: Hm, isn't it just the location of the CallSite then?